# Hibernate joincolumns with composite key different between two entities

Tags: hibernate

I have a problem when I use Hibernate JoinColumns with composite key: In my first Entity `Dossier(PK(X,Y, Z),... )` my key is composed of 3 columns (X, Y, Z) and in the second one `Person(PK(X,Y),... )` I just have **2** columns in his composite key:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @MapsId(value = "id") @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "x", referencedColumnName = "x"), @JoinColumn(name = "y", referencedColumnName = "y"), @JoinColumn(name = "z") }) DossierBean doss;
```

When I run the test, I get the following error due to a not mapped to a single property:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(CODE_ETAB, IDNT_DOSS) of fr.ressource.documentnumeriqu.db.PersDossierBean.doss referencing fr.ressource.documentnumeriqu.db.DossierBean not mapped to a single property
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1562)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1483)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1391)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a mapping like this:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ 
  @JoinColumn(name = "x", referencedColumnName = "x", insertable = false, updatable = false), 
  @JoinColumn(name = "y", referencedColumnName = "y", insertable = false, updatable = false), 
  @JoinColumn(name = "z", referencedColumnName = "z")
})
DossierBean doss;
```